# VB6 App on VM Runs Over RMM Utility But Crashes Over RDP

Tags: vb6, rdp

Alright StackOverflowians, this is a strange one, so bear with me and be kind. Also, this may be more of a question for ServerFault, but I'm hoping other developers out there may have seen this behavior and / or have some insight.

I have a VB6 application (custom built but the source code is long gone) which is running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM. When I connect to the VM using an RMM utility (ConnectWise) I can run the application as expected and everything is happy and good. However, when I connect to the VM over traditional RDP, the application crashes on startup and cites the error as COMCTL32.DLL, Exception Code:   c0000005. I login as the same user in both scenarios.

I believe that this did work over RDP once-upon-a-time, but it's been probably 6 - 8 years since I've done this.

I've been finding information about the exception code listed above as an "Access Violation" and have followed some steps to disable Data Execution Prevention, but this had no effect. If I wasn't seeing this with my own eyes, I would not believe it is happening. Would welcome any tips or information, especially if you've seen similar behavior before.

Comment: Are there some more details about the crash in the event log?

Comment: There are a few easy things you could try out: 1) play around with the compatibility settings of the application. 2) try running it "As administrator". If the app then doesn't crash, you have narrowed it down to some kind of permission issue. The above advice of investigating the event log should also be followed.

Comment: Running as Administrator provided the same results. I've been investigating the event logs but the only interesting thing I can see so far is the Exception Code: c0000005 mentioned above.

Comment: My next hint is, use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and compare the loaded DLLs and all the other things you can log with. Maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: Is the program running in any of the compatibility mode settings?